# Change Color of Check Box or Radio Button using CSS not working

Tags: css, radio-button

I'm attempting to change the color of a check box? / radio button using CSS, of some code embedded that in our site that is generated by our CMS (the CMS is a 3rd party product integrated into our site):

Looking in FireFox Dev Tools the Check Box / Radio Button element displays this HTML

```
<div class="SFchk" id="SFusrmanlog" style="" onclick="SF.usr.man('log');" set="1"><div></div><div><strong>Sign In</strong><br>with your email and password.</div></div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#SFctr .SFchk[set] > div:first-child {background-color: #f1694f; }
```

The color from this CSS is red and we want green

I've attempted the following approach, taken to change other elements colors etc, however this has not worked? This CSS was added to our Custom CSS used for our site to manipulate colors and elements etc generated by the CMS.

```
body #SFctr .SFchk[set] > div:first-child { background-color: #1F7665 !important; }
```

The check box/ radio button element also has this CSS attached to it in FireFox Dev Tools:

```
#SFctr .SFchk > div:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
#SFctr .SFchk > div {
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Suggestions? - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A radio button is a native element so you can't really change the style.
The only way that i know is to use JS.([this article could help you](http://web.archive.org/web/20101208163640/http://ryanfait.com:80/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/))

Comment: I can edit the CSS color to 1F7665 in FireFox and it makes an immediate change so I presumed that somehow I'd be to apply forced CSS to change the color like I do for other elements, buttons etc.  The article was not of assistance but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this out with this CSS and force the element to be the color I wanted!

```
#SFctr .SFchk[set]>div:first-child {background-color: #1f7665 !important;}
```

Removed the body and provided correct formatting, added to global CSS and bingo - issue sorted!